# jquery prepend to parent if child :contains x

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, conditional-statements, parent-child

If the child contains the word "Group" I want to prepend something to its parent. How do I set it up to be conditional?

```
$("#breadcrumbs ul li:nth-child(4):contains('Group')").css("display","block");
$("#breadcrumbs").prepend("<p>relevant note about Groups</p>");
```

for

```
<nav id="breadcrumbs" role="navigation">
<ul>
<li>Home</li>
<li>Section</li>
<li>People</li>
<li>Group 1</li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FqzGs/)

Comment: Does it have to be the fourth child every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/NLfmU/1/ *or* http://jsfiddle.net/anWRa/

using `.parent` api to prepend to the current child's parent

Hope it fits the need `:)`, please lemme know if I missed anything!

http://jsfiddle.net/NLfmU/

**Code**

```
$("#breadcrumbs ul li:nth-child(4):contains('Group')").css("display","block").parent().prepend("<p>relevant note about Groups</p>");
​
```

Comment: yes that's it. Didn't know about .parent that's handy. Thanks!

Comment: You realise that in your example using [`parent()`](http://jsfiddle.net/NLfmU/1/) that you're prepending the paragraph to the `ul` element (which is invalid; a `ul` can only have `li` as children)?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
var $elem = $("#breadcrumbs ul li:contains('Group')");
if ($elem.length) {
    $elem.css('display', 'block').parent().prepend("<p>relevant note about Groups</p>")
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FqzGs/5/

Comment: Looong time buddy! howz things? +1 man, using a .length check, although I reckon put in the `.parent` as well.

Comment: @Tats_innit Hey man, yes, really long time. Are you in the pink?

Comment: Neah bruv! not in pink! `:P` i knw bruv, phew good to see you!

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using a different approach:

```
$('ul li:eq(3):contains("group")').closest('nav')
    .css('display','block')
    .prepend('<p>relevant note about Groups</p>');
```

This isn't explicitly conditional, but requires the presence of the `li` containing the word 'group' in order to do anything at all.

Answer (score 2):

You were so close! `append` is what you're after though, instead of `prepend`.

Prepend will put the information BEFORE your selection, where as `append` will put it just after.

I'm guessing you want it placed just after the one that fits your requirements though, rather than before all the list? If so check out the jsfiddle :).

I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wigster/WwjAZ/) for you showing you how to do it.

**Code**

```
$("#breadcrumbs ul li:nth-child(4):contains('Group')").css("display","block")
   .append("<p>relevant note about Groups</p>");
```

​

Comment: hey bruv, I reckon he might want to `prepend` to the parent but anyhoo +1